# Decision tree with clusters of nodes

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I'd like to draw the following tree on LaTeX:
[image]
Basically it's a two-stage game with two players. Players play simultaneously on stage 1, then if they made the same decision on stage 1, stage 2 takes place. They then play simultaneously again.

It's more convenient to represent the game as a sequential tree, but at the same time, I want to emphasize that decisions take place simultaneously at each stage. So, I'd like to highlight the stages in the tree. In the hand-made example above, I simply drew boxes to separate the stages.

However, I guess some colors (say, gray on the left, white on the right) could work too.

Now I wonder which package to use for this. Can I do it with `tikz`, as it's done there: [How to draw a proper decision tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289642/how-to-draw-a-proper-decision-tree) ? Or do I need to resort to the `forest` package as here: [Tikz/Forest: highlighting level background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199853/tikz-forest-highlighting-level-background) .

In the latter case, different colors are used. However, I still prefer the "boxes" solution. How would I do it using `tikz` or `forest` ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Solved, here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

% http://texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/
% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=2.5cm, sibling distance=2.25cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{player1} = [circle, draw, text width=2em, text centered, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{player2} = [circle, draw, text width=2em, text centered, fill=red!20]
\tikzstyle{payoff} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
\node[player1] {J1}
child {
    node[player2] {J2}        
    child {
        node[payoff, label=right:
        {$(70;10)$}] {}
        edge from parent
        node[below]  {R}
    }
    child {
        node[payoff, label=right:
        {$(70;10)$}] {}
        edge from parent
        node[above] {A}
    }
    edge from parent 
    node[below]  {R}
}
child {
    node[player2] {J2}        
    child [level distance=4.75cm]
        {
        node[player1] {J1}        
        child {
            node[player2] {J2}        
            child {
                node[payoff, label=right:
                {\begin{tabular}{l}
                    $(70;30), p=\frac{1}{2}$ \\[1ex]
                    $(70;10), p=\frac{1}{2}$
                \end{tabular}
                }] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {V}
            }
            child {
                node[payoff, label=right:
                {\begin{tabular}{l}
                    $(50;50), p=0$ \\[1ex]
                    $(70;10), p=1$
                    \end{tabular}
                }] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {M}
            }
            edge from parent
            node[below] {V}
        }
        child {
            node[player2] {J2}        
            child {
                node[payoff, label=right:
                {\begin{tabular}{l}
                    $(50;50), p=1$ \\[1ex]
                    $(70;10), p=0$
                    \end{tabular}
                }] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {V}
            }
            child {
                node[payoff, label=right:
                {\begin{tabular}{l}
                    $(30;70), p=\frac{1}{2}$ \\[1ex]
                    $(70;10), p=\frac{1}{2}$
                    \end{tabular}
                }] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {M}
            }
            edge from parent
            node[above] {M}
        }
        edge from parent
        node[below]  {A}
    }
    child {
        node[payoff, label=right:
        {$(70;10)$}] {}
        edge from parent
        node[above] {R}
    }
    edge from parent     
    node[above] {A}
};
% add boxes and box labels
\draw [dashed,rounded corners](-1,-3.5) rectangle (5.5,5);
\node at (-0.5,4.5) [above=0mm, right=0mm] {\'{E}TAPE 1};
\draw [dashed,rounded corners](5.75,-3.5) rectangle (14,5);
\node at (6.25,4.5) [above=0mm, right=0mm] {\'{E}TAPE 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last four lines:

```
\draw [dashed,rounded corners](-1,-3.5) rectangle (5.5,5);
\node at (-0.5,4.5) [above=0mm, right=0mm] {\'{E}TAPE 1};
\draw [dashed,rounded corners](5.75,-3.5) rectangle (14,5);
\node at (6.25,4.5) [above=0mm, right=0mm] {\'{E}TAPE 2};
```

Were the key here.

Comment: You should add a MWE to show what you have tried. If I were to crate such a decision tree I would use pure tikz.

Comment: You could create two styles. `decision` and `result` and then draw nodes where you want them to be. Like `\node [result, right of=decision1] (win) {you won}`. (That was pseudoaLaTeX)

Comment: For boxes around multiple nodes in Tikz you can use the `fit` tikzlibrary, see http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/fit/.